# Howto do a group by and having in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After watching a couple of questions about howto create a linq query that has a groupby and where, i tried it myself but had no luck.

I want to convert this SQL query to a corresponding linq query

```
select distinct city from zipcodedata 
group by city
having city like 'zw%'
```

This query is ready in about 0,03 seconds on my development machine with 8mln records in the table. But when i try to create a a linq query like this:

```
res = _context.Zipcodes
            .GroupBy(z => z.City)
            .Where(z => z.Key.Contains(query))
            .Select(z => z.Key)
            .ToList();
```

The sql profiler tells me the following query

```
SELECT [z].[Zipcode], [z].[Street], [z].[Streetnumber], [z].[City], [z]. [Latitude], [z].[Longitude], [z].[Municipality], [z].[Province]
FROM [ZipcodeData] AS [z]
ORDER BY [z].[City]
```

I dont see a where nor a having, can some explain me why this happens.

as a footnote im using Dotnet CORE 1.1.0 with EFCore 1.1.0

Comment: Are you *just* trying to get the cities? If so, I'd probably write it as `_context.Zipcodes.Select(x => x.City).Where(c => c.Contains(query)).Distinct().ToList()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet this is not what we want.. And is still to slow.

Comment: Well what *do* you want? Your SQL looks like it's just fetching a distinct list of cities. You should clarify in the question, rather than making us guess.

Comment: I want the corresponding Linq query to what i have in SQLquery. But I already found the answer i think.

Comment: As I said, your SQL query just seems to select a distinct set of cities matching a condition. That's what the LINQ query I suggested does too. You haven't explained the difference. But it sounds like you don't care about making your question clear :(

Comment: I want to get a list of distinct cities according to the query i gave it. This is for Autocomplete list on website. The problem i face is that there are over 7.5Mln records in the table and it does not perform. After setting an Index on the City column it performs OKish with the SQL query i have in management studio (about 0,03s), but when i run use your linq query or my own linq query it is not performing. And the SQL profiler gives a totally different query to what i expect. Hope this clears up the confusion?

Comment: Not really, as you said my suggestion didn't do what you want *and* it's too slow. That suggests it's not giving the answer you want, but it sounds like it should. Don't get hung up on what SQL is generated... Concentrate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Like you suggested, I want a distinct list of cities that confirm to the query(term) I throw at it.

Comment: So in what way does my first suggested query not do that?

Comment: It does what it's supposed to do but it is not performing. `res = _context.Zipcodes.Select(x => x.City).Where(c => c.Contains(query)).Distinct().ToList();` runs in around 6,5 seconds

            `res = _context.Zipcodes.FromSql($"SELECT City FROM ZipcodeData GROUP BY City HAVING(City LIKE N'{query}%')").Select(x=>x.City).ToList();` runs in 8ms according to the SQL profiler

Comment: <sigh> Okay, so your first comment was just misleading. Have you tried moving the `Distinct` *before* the `Where` clause? What does the SQL generated by either of those look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation i found out that it is not yet possible in EF-Core according to the [Feature Comparison between EF-Core and EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features)

It states `Features not in EF Core --> Querying Data`:

> **GroupBy translation** in particular will move translation of the LINQ GroupBy operator to the database, rather than in-memory.

[See this issue on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341) exactly what i see when looking at the query in SQL Profiler :-(

I hope other people will find this answer useful